# Separate text files for over 15,000 photo files, with the same name as each photo

Tags: photos, filenames

My problem is that I have over 10.000 photo files on my laptop and wanna transfer them into the cloud to make space (and a faster laptop). But after doing that, my search engine "Everything" can't find them anymore. QUESTION - is it possible to get for EVERY SINGLE file a separate text file with the same name as each photo file? Then "Everything" can find the text file name by searching for keywords (like - Peter home wedding), so I know that I have that file already in the cloud. The same applies to more than 500 video files I have. Putting all the file names into ONE text file is no option. Searching in that single text file with just one search word, will take hours for one result.
If that can be done in one operation, would that be great.

Comment: Why do you think searching thru 10000 lines in one file will be slower than searching thru 10000 files across your filesystem? Sounds like a [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) to me.

Comment: Is the cloud service you uploaded your photos and videos to integrated into your File Explorer? If yes I don't know why the search wouldn't find them. Are you on Windows?

Comment: Simple suggestion: `dir /b /s > index.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

The simple version, creating a text file with a basename matching the photo file & with the content being the full path to the associated photo file, is easy using **PowerShell**:

```
###   Path Variables ###
$Photos    = '<path to top-level picture folder(s)>'
$PhotoInfo = '<destination path for text file creation>'

###   Create destination directory if it doesn't exist   ###
If (!(Test-Path $PhotoInfo)) { mkdir $PhotoInfo }

###   (Here-String) + (-Split operator) = Easier editing of list
$PhotoExts = -Split @'
.jpg
.jpeg
.raw
'@   ###  Edit as desired

###   Text file creation loop   ###
Get-ChildItem $Photos -Recurse | Where 'Extension' -in $PhotoExts | ForEach {
    $_.FullName | Set-Content -LiteralPath ( '{0}\{1}.txt' -f $PhotoInfo , $_.BaseName )
}
```

As written, the above will throw errors if it runs into duplicate filenames -- which is possible beause, as written, the script doesn't re-create the directory structure of the sourse path, which is searched recursively.

If you're just banging it out at the console, the above loop  can be shortened to:

```
gci $Photos -s | ? 'Extension' -in $PhotoExts | %{
    $_.FullName | sc -Lit "$PhotoInfo\$($_.BaseName).txt"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to create a separate text file with the same name as each photo file?

Try using [forfiles](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/forfiles):

`forfiles /P "C:\path\to\root\folder" /M *.jpg /S /C "cmd /c echo. > @fname.txt"`

To test the command without creating text files:

`forfiles /P "C:\path\to\root\folder" /M *.jpg /S /C "cmd /c echo @file"`

*Breakdown*:

- `/P` designates the path to the folder you wish to work with.
- `/M` searches for specific files (e.g. all JPEG files with `*.jpg`).
- `/S` recursively searches subdirectories.
- `/C` designates a command to perform for each matching file.
- `echo. > @fname.txt` creates a "blank" file with the current file name, minus its extension, plus `.txt`. The `@fname` placeholder is supplied by `forfiles`. Prefixing the command with `cmd /c` is necessary because `echo` is actually part of `cmd`.

*Caveats*:

- Double quotes are required any time spaces are present in `/P` and `/C`.
- `forfiles` seems picky about placeholder capitalization in Windows 10. In short, avoid uppercase placeholders (so e.g. `@fname` not `@FNAME`).
- `echo. > @fname.txt` creates files that technically take up space on disk (often 1KB). There are [other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702762/how-can-i-create-an-empty-file-at-the-command-line-in-windows) to create files from the command line, some of which can create true 0-byte files.